# Is there an equivalent way of doing 'lb soap' programmatically with loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strong-soap

According to [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Connecting-to-SOAP.html#generate-apis-from-the-soap-data-source%20documentation) on loopback, `lb soap` creates models of underlying soap based datasource. Is there a programmatic way to do this? I want to do it programmatically to facilitate a dynamic soap consumption through dynamically created models and datasources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a co-author and maintainer of LoopBack.*

Here is the source code implementing the command `lb soap`:

- [soap/index.js](https://github.com/strongloop/generator-loopback/blob/05186e1eb381245055643082c20ddba5f7ccfbb0/soap/index.js)
- [soap/wsdl-loader.js](https://github.com/strongloop/generator-loopback/blob/05186e1eb381245055643082c20ddba5f7ccfbb0/soap/wsdl-loader.js)

Here is the code that's generating models definition and method source code:

```
exports.generateAPICode = function generateAPICode(selectedDS, operationNames) { // eslint-disable-line max-len
  var apis = [];
  var apiData = {
    'datasource': selectedDS,
    'wsdl': selectedWsdl,
    'wsdlUrl': selectedWsdlUrl,
    'service': selectedService.$name,
    'binding': selectedBinding.$name,
    'operations': getSelectedOperations(selectedBinding, operationNames),
  };
  var code = soapGenerator.generateRemoteMethods(apiData);
  var models = soapGenerator.generateModels(apiData.wsdl, apiData.operations);
  var api = {
    code: code,
    models: models,
  };
  apis.push(api);
  return apis;
};
```

As you can see, most of the work is delegated to `soapGenerator`, which refers to [loopback-soap](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-soap) - a lower-level module maintained by the LoopBack team too. In your application, you can use `loopback-soap` directly (no need to depend on our CLI tooling) and call its API to generate SOAP-related models.

Unfortunately we don't have much documentation for `loopback-soap` since it has been mostly an internal module so far. You will have to read the source code to build a better understanding. If you do so, then we would gladly accept contributions improving the documentation for future users.